# Emacs tries to read init.el from remote machine during start-up

Tags: init-file, tramp

I have a very weird issue since a few days without being aware of any change in my set-up. I run Emacs 27.1 (on macOS installed via macports) on my laptop and on my desktop computer with a very similar set-up. Both machines run independently in the same network with an own `init.el` file located in `~/.emacs.d/`.

Since two or three days my laptop tries to load the init.el via tramp from the desktop machine. They do not share any volumes etc. I haven't used tramp for any remote editing etc. But I get a lot of messages like this in my *Message* buffer

```
Tramp: Inserting ‘/ssh:martin@XXXXX:/Users/Martin/.emacs.d/init.el’...
```

And if the desktop machine is not running Emacs halts during start-up. That's very annoying and I have no clue what is causing this.

Can anyone give me some hints how to find out what is happening?

Comment: Check the `init.el` for mentions of `ssh`. It also might be an included file, so read the whole init file carefully. You can also try commenting pieces of the file out to see which part is responsible.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that without seeing anything special. It looks like the whole init file is read and something after that causing the trouble. I will carry on and report if I find something

Comment: I found the issue in the annotations file of annotate.el. I have no idea how the reference to the annotations of a remote file has been added but everything works now as it used to.